# Trying to run a python script in cmd

Tags: python

I am trying to open a python script in cmd however, [Errno 2] is popping up! Can anyone help, i've tried everything.. even trying to add the path to the system variables.

Also, for some reason, whenever i enter a basic command like cd, 2 lines are skipped and nothing happens.

[image: error in cmd]

[image: Dir ss 1]
[image: Dir ss 2]

Comment: You aren't in the right directory.

Comment: Where is your 'snippet.py'? Try 'dir snippet.py'. I think your 'snippet.py' is not there.

Comment: @AndrewQ i tried that but this is all i got:                                         
 C:\Users\nicol>dir snippet.py
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is DA1B-1592

 Directory of C:\Users\nicol

File Not Found

Comment: run `dir` in `command prompt`, and show us the output. It will clarify most doubts if you are in the correct directory or not.

Comment: A line-skip on executing the command `cd` is expected. This command in CMD prints your `current directory`.

Comment: @Mr.Hobo I added the two screen shots or the dir command execution, they're in the actual post, i just edited it. Thank you so much for helping

Comment: @Mr.Hobo, a new error is popping up now. C:\Users\nicol>python snippet.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snippet.py", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'

Comment: @Nicole, instead of posting pics of your screen, copy and paste 'snippet.py'. Did you performed a 'pip install nltk'?

Comment: @AndrewQ this is the code in 'snippet.py' :  import nltk

text = nltk.word_tokenize("Mark and John are working at The Times of London.")
print(text)
print(nltk.pos_tag(text,tagset='universal'))
print(nltk.pos_tag(text))
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(text)
nltk.chunk.tree2conlltags(nltk.ne_chunk(tagged))

Answer (score 0):

Try to open your command line and navigate into the directory where your Python file is located. You can do this by:

```
cd "<your-path-here>"
```

Now you can see, that it does not say `C:/Nicole/...` anymore, but this specified directory.
To ensure that your file is within this folder you can do

```
dir # suggestion from comment
```

this will list all files within this folder. If you now do

```
python snippet.py
```

it will execute the Python file.

Comment: @AryanMishra then what should I do if not listen to him? you haven't helped much either, at least he tried to include a description of what i can do.

Comment: @Nicole what happens when you try out my provided solution? Are you getting an error? And if so, which? When you provide me with that information, I can maybe help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem it's still foggy. Anyway, you must install two python packages:

- nltk (as the message 'module nltk not found' suggests)
- numpy

To achieve this, use the 'pip' tool from the command prompt:

```
c:\Users\nicol> pip install nltk
c:\Users\nicol> pip install numpy
```

Depending on your Python flavour, the command may become

```
py -m pip install nltk
```

or a similar one (READ THE DOCS!) or it may use a different way to install packages.

Then, you must fix your snippet by adding these lines:

```
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
nltk.download('universal_tagset')
nltk.download('maxent_ne_chunker')
nltk.download('words')
```

just after the 'import nltk' statement.

If you plan to have fun with Python, a powerful tool like 'PyCharm' it's a 'must have'. Download it from [JetBrains site](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/).

Comment: but what's to do with numpy and nltk here?

Comment: @AryanMishra the OP changed the question in the comments... He was able to start the script, but he got an error. I think he was running Python in the wrong directory, then fixed it but another error came up... and so on.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the folder your script is saved and Shift+Right Click and select Open Powershell Here. And run the same command. Or if you really want cmd go to the address bar and type in cmd and run the command there.

Comment: He ain't in the right directory this is not the correct answer

Comment: @AryanMishra I tried cloning the git repository which includes numpy. is this still good instead of installing it through pip pls?

Comment: Pip is far better